# PrintOut() method parameters for printing an excel sheet in python

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, xlwings

I'm currently using xlwings for editing an excel file.
Now I need to print specific pages (1, 2) not the entire sheet
This is an extract of my code, working for printing just one copy of the entire sheet
(The number of copies is 0 becouse I don't know why api.Printout() prints 2 copies of the same sheet by default.)

I've tried with

```
sh2.api.PrintOut(From=1,To=2,Copies=0)
```

If anyone knows the PrintOut method parameters for python use, I believe this uses pywin32 as wrapper

The exception handler shows this:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'El número debe estar entre 1 y 32767.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

```
import xlwings as xw
import xlwings.constants  
wb=xw.Book(try.xlsx)
sh2=wb.sheets[6]
sh2.api.PrintOut(Copies=0)
```

Comment: Have a look at this issue that should solve your problem: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/504

Comment: Still there's no Usage of the PrintOut() method parameters, from that issue I've had just one parameter that works (sh2.api.PrintOut(Copies=0)

Comment: All PrintOut() parameters can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.printout . Unfortunately, they don't seem to do anything. It seems like the parameters do not get passed to Excel, or they get overwritten by something else.

Comment: I have added this issue to their git: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/504